# How would I calculate big-O for this Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I have got this algorithm

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = n; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
   for ( int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      count++;
   }
}
```

Am I right in saying that the Big-O for this would be `n/2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** The time complexity is `O(n)`.

**More details**

> Am I right in saying that the BigO for this would be n/2?

No that is accurate, in big-O notation you drop the constant part so `(1/2)n` simplifies to `O(n)`.

I am not sure where that `n/2` comes from because only the outer loop

```
for(int i = n; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
   ...
}
```

is `log2n` not `n/2`.

And with both loops together:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = n; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
   for ( int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      count++;
   }
}
```

the count would vary between `N` and `2N`.

Let us go through the calculations:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = n; i >= 1; i = i/2) {
   for ( int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      count++;
   }
}
```

The inner loop will execute `N` iterations then N/2, then N/4 ... until N/N.

In another words we have `(N + N/2 + N/4 ... N/N)` which can be simplified to `N * (1/2 + 1/4 + .. + 1/2^L))`, with `L = Log2 N`.

This `(1/2 + 1/4 + .. + )` series [is well-known for being 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF). Therefore, we can simplified  `N * (1/2 + 1/4 + .. + 1/2^L))` to `O(N)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct! This is basically a geometric progression with a quotient of `2` and the number of elements is `lg(n)` as we divide `i` by 2 each iteration of the outer loop.

`1, 2, 4, ..., n`

Using a known formula to calculate the sum, we get:

[image]

---

The reason we have `lg (n)` elements, is because we divide `i` each iteration by 2, thus we need to solve for the number of iterations `k`:

[image]